# Displaying Dynamic Content With JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a dropdown on a Page as follows, when the user selects a dropdown - I need for a different form to be produced underneath eg:

```
<div id = 'drop'>
    <select name = 'option'>
        <option>Opt1</option>
        <option>Opt2</option>
        <option>Opt3</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div id = 'NewContent'>
   //I need different content here depending on selection
</div>
```

How could I load a different form into the new Content div for each different option a user selects?

to expand on the question say I had a form:

```
<form id ='TestForm'>
First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname">
</form>
```

how would I use this:

```
$('select[name="option"]').change(function() {
   $('#NewContent').html(this.value);
});
```

to add the form as seen above?

Comment: You can use `change` event of `select`. Read http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: what should be the format of new content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way : [Fiddle link](http://fiddle.jshell.net/bsqLY/2/)

```
<div id = 'drop'>
    <select name = 'option'>
        <option value="form1">Opt1</option>
        <option value="form2">Opt2</option>
        <option value="form3">Opt3</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div id = 'NewContent'>
   //I need different content here depending on selection
   <div id="form1" style="display:none">Form1</div>
   <div id="form2"style="display:none">Form2</div>
   <div id="form3"style="display:none">Form3</div>
</div>

$('select[name="option"]').change(function() {
    $('#NewContent').find('*').hide();
   $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
});
```

Comment: thanks I will give this a shot ASAP and if it works accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$('#NewContent').html('Some New Content');` to change the content using JQuery

More information is available [here](https://api.jquery.com/html/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/)** event:

```
$('select[name="option"]').change(function() {
   $('#NewContent').html(this.value);
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kJf22/)**

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in your post:

*I need for a different form to be produced underneath*

```
$('select[name="option"]').change(function() {
   $('#NewContent').find('#'+this.value).show().siblings('form').hide();
}).change();
```

and change the form id like this:

```
<form id ='Opt1'>...</form>
<form id ='Opt2'>...</form>
<form id ='Opt3'>...</form>
```

---

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8C32B/)